# Difficulty of Skill Challenge

Tags: dnd-4e, skill-challenge, difficulty-class

I have read the other posts about this but they do not give me the info I want. My party is level 2 and they have done a few SC so far, however they always seem to be unbalanced on way or the other.

Example: They had to do a drinking contest and they needed 6 successes before getting 3 fails, I set the DC at 13. They all just used their highest powers to get by the challenge without any problem. I then made the next SC harder, they were still level 2, but the DC was 18. They would have failed if they didn't use one of their action points. I have seen the rule of thumb things and how much you should add on per level as well as how to gauge the parties skill. But they all have a really high skill at one thing or another so they make it by fine or not at all.

Question: How do I make my skill challenges hard enough for my party, but not to hard as they move through the levels and increase their skill?

We play D&D 4e

Comment: It almost sounds like you haven't read the DMG material on constructing skill challenges. Have you? I'm especially unclear on how "they all just used their highest powers" happened, because powers aren't used in skill challenges, and even if you meant "skills" instead, PCs aren't allowed to use just any skill they want to. What happened there exactly?

Answer (score 2):

In comments you responded "5 = easy 10 = medium 15 = hard 20 = really hard" as your skills DC. This is your problem. Make sure you're using DDI and all of the latest errata.

First, make sure all skill challenges have *interesting* consequences on failure, not least because then you don't have a preference on their success or failure.

Second, make sure to use the updated skills DC [chart](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105054312/http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/drdd/2010September), as that represents the correct difficulty scaling based on player level and choices.

Third, look at the literature on [skill challenges](https://critical-hits.com/features/skill-challenges/), as they're very easy to make bland and boring.

Answer (score 1):

**As Brian astutely observed double check you have the most up-to-date Skill challenge rules and guidelines.**

I no longer have an Insider account so I can't give it to you, but you should be able to check in the compendium or the published Rules Compendium or DMG2 (double checking the archived version of WOTC website for rules errata) to make sure you are up to date.

**Skill challenges should never be "Insert preferred skill here"**

A key way of making skill challenges actually challenging is limiting what skills are allowed to be used to make checks. This was quite common in published modules in Dragon magazine as well as the official adventures for Lair Assault and Encounters. Go with common-sense as to what skills would logically make sense. Trying to solve a complex, ancient mechanism to open a door, lower a bridge as a skill challenge probably wouldnt benefit from diplomacy or intimidate, for example.

The biggest challenge with regards to this is that 4e uses Arcana skill as a representation of both knowledge about magic and/or magical forces as well as aptitude with magic. Its quite common for Int based, arcana trained characters (wizards for example) to try to justify Arcana for everything , "I use arcana to magically help move the wheels" for the above example. You'll need to limit arcana to not let it outshine other skills.

**Differentiate between some skill challenge checks requiring training**

Some characters (bards, high INT characters) will have pretty high skill numbers even in skills they aren't trained in. So that one party member doesn't end up being skill monkey for everyone else, make sure that some of the checks require the PC be trained for them to contribute.

**Skills have finite uses to contribute to the skill challenge and varying rewards**

Simply put the PCs might be able to make unlimited athletic checks to operate the mechanism, but only 1 history check. Maybe that check that can only be made once is worth 2 successes.

**Give boosts for good roleplay**

Skill challenges can and should be more than just exclaiming a skill and rolling a die. Reward descriptive players with bonuses to their checks for good ideas and roleplay.